Example of a direct sum of injective sheaves which is not flabby
Let $X$ be a scheme, $(I_k)_{k \in K}$ is a family of injective $O_X$-modules, here $K$ is an infinite set. Is there an example of $X$ and such family that $\oplus_{k \in K} I_k$ is not a flabby sheaf?
It is well-known that if $X$ is locally noetherian, then $\oplus_{k \in K} I_k$ is injective (hence flabby). So, example has to be not locally noetherian.
There is special case when $X$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated scheme (concentrated). Is a direct sum of injective $O_X$-modules a flabby $O_X$-module for concentrated schemes?

Isn't $\bigoplus_{k\in K}I_k$ being flabby equivalent to each $I_k$ being flabby, so you're just asking whether injective $O_X$-modules are flabby?

Yes, that would make my question trivial, but is a direct sum of flabby sheaves flabby on a scheme? This is wrong for general topological spaces and I never seen such statements for schemes.

Ah! I see, I did not know direct sums of flabby sheaves can fail to be flabby in general.
